# New file not inheriting permissions from directory

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have an app that keeps most of its files in a directory, and I need everything in that directory to be readable and writable by any user, regardless of who was running the program that created them.

I'm installing the app using Indigo Rose's SetupFactory, and I am using their permissions facility in On Post Install:

```
File.SetPermissions(SessionVar.Expand("%AppFolder%"), 
    SID_EVERYBODY, SET_ACCESS, ALL_PERMISSIONS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT);
```

And for the most part, this works. The directory is accessible, and everything it is accessible, except for the one thing.

I have a utility program that constructs a configuration file. When it is run as administrator, the file it creates is not accessible to other users. It's properties allow access only to "SYSTEM", "Admin", and "Administrators". Files I create with Notepad, from Windows Explorer, by redirection on the command-line, etc., when running as the administrator, allow access to "Everyone", and to "Authenticated Users", as they should, given that those are the access rights provided by the directory, and the directory has Apply to: "This folder, subfolders, and files".

The question is why is this one file, created by this one app, not inheriting permissions from the directory, as it should?

There's nothing odd about the app. It's a simple C# app that constructs a string in memory, and then writes it to the file with:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

I don't see how it could be simpler.  But what could be going wrong?